# Est-ce que « Il a inspiré à Mario des sentiments hostiles à l’égard des kantiens » est correcte?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Il a inspiré à Mario des sentiments hostiles à l’égard des kantiens.

*Au sens de « Il a irrité/monté/excité Mario contre les kantiens.

Devrais-je plutôt écrire: « Il a inspiré chez Mario des sentiments hostiles à l’égard des kantiens.

Voici la phrase que j’ai pris pour modèle: Il lui a inspiré à son égard des sentiments hostiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forme habituelle est « [inspirer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inspirer) quelque chose **à** quelqu'un » ou « inspirer **à** quelqu'un quelque chose » mais la version avec **chez** n'est pas pour autant incorrecte.

Si la phrase était remaniée pour d'abord évoquer Mario, elle serait même nettement plus heureuse avec *chez* :

> Chez Mario, il a inspiré...  ✔
> À Mario, il a inspiré... (??)